# How to create AutoScalling Group using CDK for existing EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling, aws-cdk

I have been exploring AWS-CDK recently and programming language I am using is Python.
Since I am a newbie in this concept, I am trying to achieve one thing: How can I [create AutoScaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_autoscaling/AutoScalingGroup.html) Group for existing ec2 instance? I assume somewhere i need to mention the instance id, attached here by as one parameter to ASG.

Now what exact issue I am facing is, I am not able to understand how to pass the details of existing ec2 instance while configuring AutoScalingGroup. I am not creating VPC using CDK, instead I created one EC2 instance using console.

Any leads would be really helpful!!

Below is the code for AutoScalingGroup:

{
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import aws_autoscaling as autoscaling

from aws_cdk import (aws_ec2 as ec2, aws_ssm as ssm, Stack)

class AutoScalingStack(Stack):
def **init**(self, scope:Construct, id: str,vpc: ec2.Vpc, **kwargs) -> None:
super().**init**(scope,**kwargs)

```
    autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(self, "ASG",
    vpc=vpc,
    launch_template= launch_template
```

)

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an image (AMI) from the existing EC2 instance. This will capture all of the settings of the instance. Then you will be able to use the newly created AMI in the Auto scaling group that you create with the CDK using the `machine_image` parameter https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_autoscaling/AutoScalingGroup.html - The auto scaling group would then create ec2 instances based on the same AMI. This is how you would basically "pass in" the existing settings of the current ec2 instance into your CDK auto scaling group.

Comment: Ok, but what config to passed for "Vpc" field? Since it is expecting something of IVpc.

Comment: Then you need to use the `fromLookup` ec2 method to bring in the VPC into your CDK app https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Vpc.html#static-fromwbrlookupscope-id-options

Comment: Here's another link to the docs that contains an example of the lookup https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.VpcLookupOptions.html#vpcid